# Vulkan execution dependency chaining

Tags: synchronization, vulkan, barrier

I'm struggling to understand when exactly execution dependency chains are formed.

1. The vulkan spec states:

   > An execution dependency chain is a sequence of execution dependencies that form a happens-before relation between the first dependency’s **ScopedOps1** and the final dependency’s **ScopedOps2**. For each consecutive pair of execution dependencies, a chain exists if the intersection of **Scope2nd** in the first dependency and **Scope1st** in the second dependency is not an empty set.

   and:

   > Including a particular pipeline stage in the first synchronization scope of a command implicitly includes logically earlier pipeline stages in the synchronization scope. Similarly, the second synchronization scope includes logically later pipeline stages.

   Now consider slide 11 of [this presentation](https://www.lunarg.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/Vulkan-Synchronization-SIGGRAPH-2021.pdf).

   The second synchronization scope of `Barrier1` includes logically later stages as per spec. So if `Barrier1.dstMask` is `DRAW_INDIRECT`, it *DOES* include `COMPUTE_SHADER`. Similarly, the first synchronization scope of `Barrier2` includes logically earlier stages as per spec. So if `Barrier2.srcMask` is `COMPUTE_SHADER`, it *DOES* include `DRAW_INDIRECT`. Then why is it, according to this slide, that this configuration *DOES NOT* constitute a execution dependency chain between the two barriers?

   Also, if I set `Barrier1.dstMask` to `BOTTOM_OF_PIPE`, how does it suddenly form a chain with anything other than `BOTTOM_OF_PIPE` in the srcMask of the next barrier? The spec clearly states `BOTTOM_OF_PIPE` is equivalent to `ALL_COMMANDS_BIT` with access flags set to 0 when specified in the *first* scope, not the second??

   Is the linked presentation wrong?

2. I was wondering how to synchronize separate render passes, or synchronize something from inside a render pass with something outside a render pass. After scouring the internet I found you can specify `BOTTOM_OF_PIPE` in the second scope and chain onto it with either `BOTTOM_OF_PIPE` or `ALL_COMMANDS` in the first scope of a next dependency ([as suggested here](https://community.khronos.org/t/synchronization-between-seperate-renderpasses/7578/6), and slide 12 in the presentation linked above).

   Is this correct? I can find nothing in the spec to support this.

Comment: People are allowed to be wrong. When commenting other people work, should probably request comment from them first. It becomes tiresome to be constantly proxy-debuging other people's documents and code, while they should be the one resposible for maintaining it. If one has to decide between random person and the specification, then by default the specification is right. Sorry, bit tired of frequent "why does this person's work says\does X" questions. Seems like a trivial error in the presentation where the two columns are swapped there.

Comment: Sorry to add to the pile of these questions. Did not actually notice the trivial error. It got pretty clouded for me due to all the confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Execution dependency chaining applies universally to all the synchronization primitives. Of which `VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL` Subpass Dependencies are nearly the same thing as regular Pipeline Barriers.

Execution dependency chains are formed whenever it is satisfiable to match both the scopes at the same time. That is, if you can hypothetically imagine some queue operation that could match both the second sync scope of first sync command, and the first sync scope of the second sync command, then execution dependency chain is formed. The imaginary operation need **not** be real, actually recorded, nor executed.

For example if I have two Pipeline Barriers and `barr1.dstStageMask` is `STAGE_COMPUTE`, and `barr2.srcStageMask` is also `STAGE_COMPUTE`, then it is an execution dependency chain. I could imagine there is a `vkCmdDispatch` recorded between the two. That command would match both the scopes, therefore it is a chain.

If `barr1.dstStageMask` is `VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_BOTTOM_OF_PIPE_BIT` and `barr2.srcStageMask` is `VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TOP_OF_PIPE_BIT`, then there is no chain. Both the scopes are not satisfiable at the same time. It is impossible to imagine any operation that would match both of them, therefore no execution dependency chain is formed.

(It is explained above in terms of pipeline stages at the risk of losing completeness, but keep in mind the pipeline stage is only a one part of the description of the synchronization scope as it is specified per each synchronization primitive in the specification. For example, a Fence would chain with nearly everything despite not really being specified in terms of pipeline stages)

---

ad nr. 1, seems like a trivial error in the presentation where the two columns are swapped there:

[image]

`VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_BOTTOM_OF_PIPE_BIT` is not the equivalent of `VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_ALL_COMMANDS_BIT` in the context of `dstStageMask`. It would be interpreted as `VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_NONE` in that context. So that's a tell.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Did not actually notice the columns could be swapped due to my confusion, that clears it up beautifully.

As for my second question, I still don't quite understand. I understand how the stages can be used to chain if they're anything other than `BOTTOM_OF_PIPE` or `TOP_OF_PIPE`. But if both `barr1.dstMask` and `barr2.srcMask` are `BOTTOM_OF_PIPE` (neither are top of pipe), how does that form a chain? As I understand it bottom/top of pipe don't match any actual (or imagined?) commands?

Comment: @Invalid Well, it works because the specification says it works. Something like a Fence needs to chain with nearly everything, or if it didn't that would be a decent specification hole (`vkWaitIdle` would not ensure device is idle). All the commands go through `BOTTOM_OF_PIPE`, they just nominaly do not do any useful work in it. I can imagine a fake command `vkCmdBogus()` which is specified that it laser prints "Hello, world!" onto your baguette in the `BOTTOM_OF_PIPE` stage. Therefore it can match both scopes. The predicate is satisfiable, so a chain is established.

Comment: I see, I think the confusion lies in that the spec says bottom/top of pipe may specify "no stage of execution", implying it is not a stage in and of itself where commands may happen (even imaginary). But I guess it can actually be seen as a stage. Thanks for taking the time to answer!

Comment: @Invalid It is a stage for sure, though a special one mostly for the purposes of expressing the end and beginning. More confusingly though new Vulkan added `STAGE_NONE`, which presumably should still chain with these old stages and work the same way.